# How to use Mongo Java Driver to perform some kind of admin command?

Tags: mongodb

In Java Driver of MongoDB, does it support reading mongo shell command directly? I am creating a Mongo client for Mongo dba in Java and want to allow users to type any kind of Mongo shell commands but I am not sure whether it is possible to do all dba tasks through Mongo Java Driver.
For example, when users type `show dbs` or `show collections` in mongo shell, a list of databases or collections will be shown. Also dba can type `rs.status(), rs.config()` commands to execute some admin tasks. I wonder whether mongo java driver supports that kind of input. I know I can use some API from the Java driver like `database.runCommand(new Document(...));` but it needs some translating tasks between shell command and Java methods. Whether is there a better way to do that?

Comment: What is the idea behind sending the shell commands ? Why can't you execute the equivalent java API method ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected CommandResult runReplicaSetStatusCommand(final Mongo pMongo) {
        // Check to see if this is a replica set... if not, get out of here.
        final CommandResult result = pMongo.getDB("admin").command(
                new BasicDBObject("replSetGetStatus", 1));

        final String errorMsg = result.getErrorMessage();

        if (errorMsg != null && errorMsg.indexOf("--replSet") != -1) {
            System.err
                    .println("This is not a replica set - not testing secondary reads");
            return null;
```

get full example at : http://massapi.com/source/bitbucket/12/14/1214103355/src/test/java/com/mongodb/util/TestCase.java.html#307

Comment: Does that mean all admin commands I can use through Java driver?

Comment: well from what i see. most of them for sure. you just need to play around a little. what is it that you are very specifically interested ?

Comment: I am interested in reading plain mongo shell command, like "show dbs", "rs.status()", "rs.config()", then put them directly into Java driver class. I am not sure whether it is possible.